# jquery script not working in ie7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

I have the following jquery that I wrote:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('div.contentTxtBox#home').addClass('current').show();

    $('a.menu').click(function() {

    $('div.contentTxtBox.current').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 700).removeClass('current');
    $('div.contentTxtBox#' + this.id).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 700).addClass('current');
    $('a.menu.current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    return false;

    });

});
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.contentTxtBox {
    padding:20px;
    width:321px;
    height:330px;
    background:#E0E0DB;
    position:absolute;
    display:none;
}
.contentTxtBox.current {
    display:block;
}
```

So it's working in every browser except ie7. In addition to this .js, I'm also using bxslider.js and spry accordions js.

Any suggestions? I'd be happy for it simply to appear, rather than slide across.

Many TIA :-)

Comment: Not an answer, but:

`$('div.contentTxtBox#home')` ... Talk about over-selectification. ID's are unique, there's no need to quantify your selector with both a tag name and a class. `$('#home')` would work just the same, and be faster.

Comment: Do you have duplicate IDs?  Your `click` event is for an anchor, but you're using the same ID to try and find a `<div>`, so I'm a bit confused :)

Comment: Actually, that may be part of your problem. ID's are really, really, supposed to be unique. This line: `$('div.contentTxtBox#' + this.id)` indicates that you are selecting a DOM node that has the same ID as the anchor that is triggering the click event... a big no-no. I'm surprised it works anywhere.

Comment: Hi both! Yes, my menu uses ids to find the corresponding .contentTxBox. So the menu has .button#services that corresponds to the .contentTxtBox#services.

Comment: @circey - You can't repeat IDs in a page, they need to be unique, you should instead do something like `href="#services"`

Comment: Well, you can't do that. ID's are (supposed to be) unique in any given document. You'll need to find a different (better) solution.

Comment: @jason, really? I thought that was the whole idea of jquery; that it's easy to select elements using ids and that +this.id was commonly used. I'm not a seasoned jquery coder by any stretch of the imagination so please excuse stupid coding!

Comment: Ok, thanks all for the feedback. I get it now :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had menu buttons: .button#home, which corresponded to .contentTxtBox#home.

Renamed .contentTxtBox ids with a prefix of "ctb": .contentTxtBox#ctbhome.

Thanks everyone for this! Had no idea it was bad!

Answer (score 0):

with this line,

```
$('div.contentTxtBox#' + this.id).show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 700).addClass('current');
```

this proves you have duplicate `id`'s, which is not valid html. IE seems to hate that.. ;)